# How to get the name of parent directory in Python?

Tags: python, variables, directory

I have a program in python that prints out information about the file system... I need to know to save the name of the parent directory to a variable...

For example, if a tiny bit of the file system looked like this: 
**ParentDirectory**
**ChildDirectory**
**SubDirectory**
If I was inside of *ChildDirectory*, I would need to save the name *ParentDirectory* to a certain string... here is some ***pseudo code***:

`import os`
`var = os.path.parent()`

`print var`
On a side note, I am using Python 2.7.6, so I need to be compatible with 2.7.6...

Comment: Because I think the downvote description "This question does not show any research effort" fits.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get the complete file path for the script resides using `__file__` variable , then you can use `os.path.abspath()` to get the absolute path of your file , and then use `os.path.join()` along with your current path , and the parent directory descriptor - `..` in most operating systems , but you can use os.pardir (to get that from python , so that it is truly platform independent) and then again get its absolute path to get the complete path of current directory, then use it with same logic again to get its parent directory.

Example code -

```
import os,os.path
curfilePath = os.path.abspath(__file__)

# this will return current directory in which python file resides.
curDir = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(curfilePath, os.pardir))

# this will return parent directory.
parentDir = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(curDir, os.pardir))
```

Comment: so if the path to the file "c" is /a/b/c and I want to extract "b" ( the parent directory name) , this will work? I think that is what the OP wanted, Not the parent dir. path, but rather it's name.